# Why does conditional NExpectation fail for a multivariate distribution?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions, conditional

To give an example for a multiparametric distribution let us take a binormal distribution:

```
binormalDist = With[
    {
       μ = { 0, 0 },
       σ = { 1, 1 },
       ρ = 7/10
    },
    BinormalDistribution[ μ, σ, ρ ]
];
```

Calculating the conditional expectation in simple cases works out:

```
NExpectation[2 x + 3 \[Conditioned] x < 1., {x, y} \[Distributed] binormalDist ]
```

> 2.4248

and so does this too:

```
NExpectation[2 x + 3 \[Conditioned] y == 2., {x, y} \[Distributed] binormalDist ]
```

> 5.8

but

```
NExpectation[2 x + 3 \[Conditioned] (x < 1 && y == 2.), {x, y} \[Distributed] binormalDist ]
```

is returned unevaluated (as is `Expectation` with identical args)

> NExpectation[ 3+ 2 x [Conditioned] x < 1 && y == 2., {x, y} [Distributed] 
>         BinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, {1, 1}, 7/10]]

Why? And how can it be solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since

```
Probability[x < 1 && y == 2,
            {x, y} \[Distributed] BinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, {1, 1}, 7/10]]
   0
```

and the PDF of the purported conditional distribution has that expression as a denominator, this may be the reason why your attempt remains unevaluated.

---

Using [`Method -> "Trace"`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NExpectation.html#87352548), we see that `NExpectation[]` is attempting to evaluate the following expression internally:

```
NIntegrate[(3 + 2 x)
           PDF[Statistics`Library`ConditionalDistribution[x < 1 && y == 2,
               {x, y} \[Distributed] BinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, {1, 1}, 7/10]], {x, y}],
           {x, -∞, ∞}, {y, -∞, ∞}, AccuracyGoal -> ∞, Compiled -> Automatic,
           PrecisionGoal -> Automatic, WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision,
           MinRecursion -> 1]
```

where we see that `` Statistics`Library`ConditionalDistribution[] `` is used to represent the distribution induced by the conditional expectation. Notice that both `` PDF[Statistics`Library`ConditionalDistribution[x < 1, {x, y} \[Distributed] BinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, {1, 1}, 7/10]], {x, y}] `` and `` PDF[Statistics`Library`ConditionalDistribution[y == 2, {x, y} \[Distributed] BinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, {1, 1}, 7/10]], {x, y}] `` evaluate to expressions, but `` PDF[Statistics`Library`ConditionalDistribution[x < 1 && y == 2, {x, y} \[Distributed] BinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, {1, 1}, 7/10]], {x, y}] `` does not.

If you think *Mathematica* should be able to evaluate combined conditions like in the OP, you could try writing [a suggestion to support](https://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/email/).

Comment: Yes, this probability is 0, that's the correct answer. But instead of this results, conditional expected value  has a correct value


0.458101


via the formula



`NIntegrate[(2 x + 3)*
  E^(-((x^2 - 2 *0.7 x*2 *2 + 2^2)/(2 (1 - 0.7^2))))/(
  2 \[Pi] Sqrt[1 - 0.7^2]), {x, -\[Infinity], 1.}]`

Answer (score 0):

As can be seen from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Conditional_expectation_with_respect_to_a_random_variable_2) for two continuous random variables the conditional expectation is given as:

\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}\left(X|Y=y\right) = \int_\mathcal{X}x \frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_Y(y)}dx
\end{align}

So with the corresponding definitions:

```
distXY = BinormalDistribution[ {0, 0}, {1, 1}, 7/10 ];

fY[2] = PDF[ MarginalDistribution[ distXY, 2], 2 ]; (* a constant value > 0 *)

fXY[x_, 2] = PDF[ distXY, {x, 2} ];
```

I would assume that we then get the conditional expectation as:

```
condExp = 1/fy[2] NIntegrate[ (2 x + 3) fXY[x,2], {x,-∞, 1} ]
```

> 1.18159

Comment: @JimB Excuse my ping, but I am quite sure, you would no the correct result here or could point me into the right direction. I would greatly appreciate your help here.